# dynamic jquery mobile pages with knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I am trying to generate jquery mobile pages like described here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/pages/page-dynamic.html

I do not like however the way the HTML it's generated, it's hard to update this kind of code.
I am thinking there must be some better ways instead of concatenating html tag strings like that.
For example, I am thinking about doing these two steps:

1.have a knockout template

```
<script type="text/html" id="category-template">
            <ul data-bind="foreach: Categories" data-role="listview">
                <li>
                    <a data-bind="{attr : { href : $parent.GetCategoryUrl(arguments[0][0])}}">
                        <img src="../res/placeholder.png" alt="" />
                        <span data-bind="text: Name"></span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
<script>
```

2.in the showCategory function, I am thinking I can get the HTML code from the script node which is the template and inject it as described in the page from the jquery mobile site.

However, this doesn't look trivial. For example, I don't see how to get the script node HTML. I am not sure even if the bindings will work. 
Also, I need to get access to the view model of the current page(still existing) in order to get the data which is actually rendered. I don't see how i can get access to the view model.

Is there a better way to do it?

Thanks!